# starting the conversation client, joining a conversation, and subscribing to conversation changes on twilio using javascript client sdk and angular

Tags: javascript, angular, twilio, subscribe, twilio-programmable-chat

A quick note and edit, it looks like this tutorial might be a winner
https://recursive.codes/blog/post/37

I am using the twilio conversation javascript client sdk on a angular 8 project.

Subscriptions, and async operations are still something I am working on understanding. My entire component that I am using twilio conversations on is below. After i will list my problems.

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Client as ConversationsClient} from '@twilio/conversations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shochat-contentcreator-chat',
  templateUrl: './shochat-contentcreator-chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shochat-contentcreator-chat.component.scss']
})
export class ShochatContentcreatorChatComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() twiliochattoken = null;
  conversationsclient;
  currentconnectionstate = null;


  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log('here we are and stuff tho');
    let initConversations = async () => {
      this.conversationsclient = await ConversationsClient.create(this.twiliochattoken);
      this.conversationsclient.join().then((result) => {
        console.log('here is the result of joining the conversation');
        console.log(result);
      });
    }


    this.conversationsclient.on("connectionStateChanged", (state) => {
      if (state == "connecting") {
        this.currentconnectionstate = 'connecting';
      }
      if (state == "connected") {
        this.currentconnectionstate = 'connected';
      }
      if (state == 'disconnecting') {
        this.currentconnectionstate = 'disconnecting';
      }
      if (state == 'disconnected') {
        this.currentconnectionstate = 'disconnected';
      }
      if (state == 'denied') {
        this.currentconnectionstate = 'denied';
      }

    });

    this.conversationsclient.on("conversationJoined", (conversation) => {
      console.log('here is the result of the conversationJoined hook');
      console.log(conversation);
    });
  }


}
```

The below code snippet from the above is the problem:

```
this.conversationsclient.on("connectionStateChanged", (state) => {
          if (state == "connecting") {
            this.currentconnectionstate = 'connecting';
          }
......
```

I am getting the error that the code cannot perform the `.on` function on undefined. Which makes sense, the above function is being called on the `init` function.

`conversationsclient` is undefined still. However what is the proper way to put this code? Inside the `await ConversationsClient.create(.....)` code?

Will that create the subscription that I want for when state changes?

Also how is my code looking based on its intent. I feel like I have missed the mark and not sure if I am close or far from hitting it.

im referencing the following docs

https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/initializing-sdk-clients

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial has the answer. I need to use a service.

chatservice:

```
import {EventEmitter, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as Twilio from 'twilio-chat';
import Client from "twilio-chat";
import {Util} from "../util/util";
import {Channel} from "twilio-chat/lib/channel";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {AuthService} from "./auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {

  public chatClient: Client;
  public currentChannel: Channel;
  public chatConnectedEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()
  public chatDisconnectedEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) { }

  connect(token) {
    Twilio.Client.create(token).then( (client: Client) => {
      this.chatClient = client;
      this.chatConnectedEmitter.emit(true);
    }).catch( (err: any) => {
      this.chatDisconnectedEmitter.emit(true);
      if( err.message.indexOf('token is expired') ) {
        localStorage.removeItem('twackToken');
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    });
  }

  getPublicChannels() {
    return this.chatClient.getPublicChannelDescriptors();
  }

  getChannel(sid: string): Promise<Channel> {
    return this.chatClient.getChannelBySid(sid);
  }

  createChannel(friendlyName: string, isPrivate: boolean=false) {
    return this.chatClient.createChannel({friendlyName: friendlyName, isPrivate: isPrivate, uniqueName: Util.guid()});
  }

}
```

component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.isConnecting = true;
  this.chatService.connect(localStorage.getItem('twackToken'));

  this.conSub = this.chatService.chatConnectedEmitter.subscribe( () => {
    this.isConnected = true;
    this.isConnecting = false;
    this.getChannels();
    this.chatService.chatClient.on('channelAdded', () => {
      this.getChannels();
    });
    this.chatService.chatClient.on('channelRemoved', () => {
      this.getChannels();
    });
    this.chatService.chatClient.on('tokenExpired', () => {
      this.authService.refreshToken();
    });
  })

  this.disconSub = this.chatService.chatDisconnectedEmitter.subscribe( () => {
    this.isConnecting = false;
    this.isConnected = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: I too followed the same tutorial in my Angular 12 app and ran into few issues. Could you please help to solve this? 
core.js:6456 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ChatService -> Client -> Client -> Client]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Client!